# Will a MMBT5087 saturate with a 1K resistor in the base?

Tags: pic, usb, transistors, bjt, pnp

I am using the configuration in picture and the MMBT5087 PNP transistor. I am not using the top base resistor, just the lower one, so there will be 5V on the base. 
[image: buffer configuration to protect chip when not powered from bus voltage]

My question is: Using a 1K resistor will it saturate? And is it ok to apply 5V directly on the base or it might damage the device?

I want to use 1K to keep the base current as low as possible.

[Datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MM/MMBT5087.pdf)

Comment: When I clicked on your link nothing happened, so I gave up after a few seconds.  Also, provide a link to the transistor datasheet, this makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Someone edited it, sorry not my fault

Answer (score 4):

"Saturation" is usually defined as the point where hFE drops to 10. So work out the voltage across the base resistor (without chasing your circuit and datasheet, I'm guessing 5V - Vbe = 4.3V), so 4.3ma base current. So, if your load current Ic < 43mA, the transistor is technically in saturation. If I've guessed wrong, put in the correct numbers and decide for yourself.